# Can I use two different PSU cables from the same brand?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, power

I have an old rig and a new rig, the "old" one is using a previous generation AX850 (the ones with the gold writing on the side, not the red), and a new RM 850.

I want to add a second graphics card to the rig with the AX850 in it, but the PSU cables that split up in two 6+2 pins for PCI-e have 12 pin connectors on the PSU end, whereas the same cable on the RM850 has an 8 pin connector on the PSU end, and splits off to 2x 6+2 pin.

They're both Corsair power supplies, and as far as I know they both use a 12 volt rail, but would it be safe to connect the cable from the RM850 to the AX850?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's no reason they wouldn't work, and knowing they're from the same vendor helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standardisation for the connectors on the PSU end of modular cables. Even within one PSU brand the connector pin-outs sometimes vary.

Do not use a modular cable from one PSU on another PSU without first using a multimeter to test that the pin out is correct.